# Sorting a pre-defined list of names

Tags: c, strcmp, strcpy

I'm working on Chapter 8 Challenge 3 from C Programming for the Absolute Beginner 2nd Edition. The program is supposed to sort an array of names alphabetically.

My program doesn't work. The main function without `sort()` works, but the sort function is messed up; also `strcmp()` seems to be used incorrectly, based on warning messages.

The compiler I'm using is gcc and I wrote the code with nano.

```
/* Uses strcmp() in a different function
   to sort a list of names in alphabetical order */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort(char*, int);

void main() {
    char strStates[4][11] = { "Florida", "Oregon", "California", "Georgia" };
    sort(*strStates, 4); // 4 is the number of string in the array

    printf("\nFour States Listed in Alphabetical Order\n");

    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        printf("\n%s", strStates[x]);
}

void sort(char* strNames, int iStrings) {
    char strPlaceholder[11] = { 0 };
    int x;
    int y;

    for(x = 0; x < iStrings; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y < iStrings - 1; y++) {
            if(strcmp(strNames[y], strNames[y + 1]) > 0) {
                strcpy(strPlaceholder, strNames[y + 1]);
                strcpy(strNames[y + 1], strNames[y]);
                strcpy(strNames[y], strPlaceholder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, put your code in

Comment: Please include your program text directly in the question.  Copy'n'paste the code into the edit box.  Make sure it looks OK, ignoring the previewl  Then select the code and use the **`{}`** button above the box to indent it.  Now check the preview.  Make sure there's no tabs in the code you copy; that will wreck the layout when you indent it.

Comment: The argument type of `sort` is incorrect.

Comment: Think about it.  Are we supposed to manually retype your code to try it?  Paste the text!  Include your full error messages, too.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: don't include the image — mark the question for closure "unclear what you're asking".  Don't encourage people to leave images.  All else apart, it isn't possible to copy'n'paste the code to test it, or see what it really says.

Comment: Sorting logic is wrong. you should fix it first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Most people with coming to this question are going to click the link.  Why not make it visible without the extra hassle? The OP was already prompted to fix it.  Give the OP a chance to.

Comment: They've had half an hour — that's long enough.  I disagree, but I won't undo any subsequent attempt to insert the image.  I think inserting it lets the OP off the hook when they should not be let off the hook — but I'll bow to the collective preference of the denizens of SO.

Comment: [Hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31016254/971127)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not meant as an answer but as a hint to let you get forward. A two dimensional array like `char[4][11]` is something different than a pointer to a (sequences of) characters like `char*`.

Suppose the following code:

```
char *s = "Florida"; // lets pointer 's' point to a sequence of characters, i.e. { 'F', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'd', 'a', '\0' }
char arr[2][11] = { "Florida", "New York" };
```

Then an expression like `s[1]` is equivalent to `*(s + sizeof(char))`, which is `*(s+1)`, whereas an expression like `arr[1]` is equivalent to `*(arr + sizeof(char[11]))`, which is `*(arr + 11)`, not `*(arr + 1)`. The "sizeof"-part is done by the compiler and is derived from the type of the variable. Hence an argument of type `char*` behaves different than an argument of type `char[11]`.

The following code might help you forward:

```
void print (char array[][11], int n) {

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d:%s\n",i,array[i]);
}

int main() {

    char strStates[4][11] = { "aer", "adf", "awer", "aert" };
    print (strStates,4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Oops, the attempt of explaining a sequence of characters took the complete wrong way :-)